# Allocate two stack frames in LLVM

Tags: c++, vector, stack, llvm, simd

I am developing a LLVM compiler for a SIMD architecture. This architecture is separated in two parts, being the CP(Control Processor) which only handles the scalar data and PE(Processing Element) array which handles the vector data. The scalar data memory and the vector data memory is separated. Only CP can access the scalar data memory, while the PE array can only access the vector data memory.

Normally, during the program execution, all the local data is stored in the stack, which is located in the scalar data memory. However, if a vector is defined, it will also be stored in the scalar data memory, instead of the vector data memory which is the place where the vector should be stored. Considering the processor which is responsible for the vector calculation can not access the scalar data memory directly, the easiest way is to make the CP access the elements of the vector and broadcast them to the PE array one by one, which is going to be very annoying and take a lot of cycles.

I am wondering if it is possible to allocate two stack frames at the same time, one is for the scalar data and another one is for the vector data. In this case, we also need two stack pointers and frame pointers. If it is possible, how to implement this in LLVM?

I know it is a kind of tricky question. In LLVM, I can only define one stack pointer register and frame pointer register. Also the process of calculating the stack size is executed automatically by the llvm.

If some of you have any idea, please tell me.

Thank you very much.